# How come numeric scale returns an additional digit

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a column that is `varchar`, and I am trying to convert it to `numeric(8,2)` to return it like this `1.00`, but its returning it like this instead `1.000`

Example:

```
 Select 
   Convert(numeric(8,2),WholesaleCost) * 2.2)
 FROM Table
```

This Returns `50.900`

Seems like when I reduce the scale to `numeric(8,1)` instead of `numeric(8,2)` it returns how I want it, which is `50.90`

Does anyone know why its doing this? Why its adding an additional scale digit to the result?  Shouldnt it be `50.9` when i do `numeric(8,1)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are doing `numeric(8,2) * numeric(2,1)` and the resultant datatype is `numeric(11,3)`

When multiplying two `numeric` numbers `e1 * e2` the result has precision `p1 + p2 + 1`  and scale `s1 + s2` as per [Precision, Scale, and Length](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190476%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx)